# Draw a dotted circle outside and circle in Android View

Tags: android, view

if i want to Draw circle like this

[image]

see 30 , I want to know how to draw in Android , without xml , Thanks.

I try to design No 30, this is my code :

```
            textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            shape = new GradientDrawable();
            shape.setShape(GradientDrawable.OVAL);
            shape.setCornerRadii(new float[]{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0});
            shape.setColor(style.getColor());  
            shape.setStroke(6, Color.parseColor("#CF6194"), 10,8);
            this.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
            textView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, (float) 1.0));
            textView.setBackground(shape);
            this.addView(textView);
```

but It's ugly...

I know No.11 code :

```
            circleDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
            circleDrawable.getPaint().setColor(style.getColor());
            circleDrawable.getPaint().setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE); 
            circleDrawable.getPaint().setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[]{30f,20f}, 1f));
            circleDrawable.getPaint().setStrokeWidth(4);
```

Comment: You can create the layer-list programmatically. Can you show us what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the way to achieve my question.

https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
<shape android:shape="oval" >
    <stroke
        android:color="#FF00FF"
        android:dashWidth="2px"
        android:dashGap="3px"
        android:width="1px"/>
    <size
        android:width="15dp"
        android:height="15dp"/>
</shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <stroke android:color="@android:color/transparent"
            android:width="5dp"/>
        <solid android:color="#f00"/>
        <size
            android:width="10dp"
            android:height="10dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I need is programmatically , not xml ...